# Squaring Circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have to study biomedical electronic, but there is a problem. I searched but could not find things I want.

How can I design squaring circuit with op-amp, if input is a 50 mV and I have to get output value = X^2. = 2500 mV for example?

Comment: As always, AN-31.

Comment: \$50^2 \neq 250 \$ ;) You need a multiplier circuit. This paper will help you: http://nopr.niscair.res.in/bitstream/123456789/6896/1/IJPAP%2048(1)%2067-70.pdf Also, as @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams stated, "Opamp Circuit Collection" will help you as well: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla140b/snla140b.pdf

Comment: @Mehmet Do you mean a circuit that converts a sine wave to a square wave? Is your input going from 0V to 50mV, or is it -25mV to +25mV?

Comment: Your question is unclear, are you looking for a circuit that takes \$ V_{in}\$  as input and produces \$ \frac{V_{in}^2}{10}\$ as output?

Comment: why only 250mV square wave. what frequency , source impedance, and Vmin input will determine gain and hysteresis required with full scale clipping and R divider to reduce to 250mV.. details please.

Comment: @Rohat Kılıç: nobody claimed that \$50^2=250\$. By saying that the squaring circuit should output 250mV for an input of 50mV the OP just defined the otherwise arbitrary nomalization constant to be 10mV because \$(\frac{50mv}{10mV})^2=\frac{250mV}{10mV}\$.

Comment: @SteveG ı mean that think about an input has a X value and output have to give me X^2 .

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 ı study on biomedical signal therefore signals have small value and ı have to take a signal that input value is X and output value is X^2. Other components are not important for now

Comment: _Why_ do you need to square the signal?

Comment: @Mehmet: Wait, why do you need to square it then? It sounds like all you're after is an amplifier. Squaring the result is a nonlinearity... what's the purpose of squaring it rather than linear gain?

Comment: @BruceAbbott, i'll bet it's because he wants a power signal.  if the OP wants r.m.s., he'll need to square root also.  it will seem silly if this squared biomed signal gets sampled and inputted into an embedded processor or DSP, in which the squaring can be done with a single instruction.

Comment: @PeterK This is an experimental circut and professor wanted from me that I answer it but ı could not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the difficulty in calibration of a true Analog multiplier, it is best to consider the use of a suitable chip with factory laser trimmed offset and gain IC, such as ;

[www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD534.pdf](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD534.pdf)

[image]

There is a wide selection range and many suppliers, AD835
AD633
AD734
AD834
AD538
AD539
AD632
AD534
AD532

http://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11106?doc=AD534.pdf&p0=1&lsrc=pst&doc=AD534.pdf&p0=1&lsrc=pst#/ps5=select%20all

Lowest cost is the AD633 < $5 (1k)
[image]

Comment: If you only need 1, there is an EVAL board http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/evaluation-hardware-and-software/evaluation-boards-kits/eval-ad633.html#eb-buy