# Are there well known simple operationnal amplifier circuits designs to make purely analog squaring amplifier (for experimental analog computing)?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, analog-computer

In order to make analog calculation (for analog regulator simulation), what would be the means to make an squaring amplifier ?

- There is an obvious solution with a multiplier circuit as pointed
  [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/263056/squaring-circuit);
- I also imagined using a mosfet like in the following drawing and in
  this case I would need another similar circuit for the negative part
  of the signal;

but before trying to effectively design it, I wondered if there would be other well known simple solution.

---

Edit : Some people seem to dislike the application of analog computing. Just think of it as an educational application.

Edit2 : To make things more precise, let's say that to avoid saturation problems, the identity element would be 10v, So for a 1v input we get a 0.1v output and for a 0.1v input, we get 1mV output, and it would be even better if we had a circuit which would give the same positive output for the same negative inputs.

[image]

Comment: depending on your definition of simple, one method that is very effective is to run the signal through a noise-shaped delta sigma converter, which turns it into a bit stream. Use the bit stream to switch the signal polarity, and filter the output. Linear (now Analog) use this technique in their true RMS converters.

Comment: [This question and answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/373492/analog-analog-multiplication-part-of-a-hybrid-cpu-for-fun?noredirect=1&lq=1) may be of some interest as it also uses a technique similar to that mentioned by Neil above.

Comment: I you convert it into a bit stream, you loose the properties of being an analog circuit. The mathematics behind this are not the same anymore (z-transform instead of laplace transform), and it can cause instability in a regulation system, if you try to model it as if it was analog

Comment: This is too broad as you have failed to state any specifics of the application requirement as it impacts the performance required of the solution and failed to give any actual justification for why an analog solution is required.  There are many ways to solve problems but you give no basis for picking the appropriate one, thus failing the SE requirement for specific answerability.  All of this was pointed out when you tried to reopen a similarly flawed question.  It was explained then what you would need to have a valid question, essentially none of which you have provided.

Comment: @Chris Stratton : did you ever heard about analog computers ? This is a very specific scope where one combine "all purpose" modules in order to build regulators and differential equations simulators. I wonder how I can be more specific than that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer#Electronic_analog_computers_2

Comment: Analog computers existed, but are largely extinct as they have many implementation problems.  You've failed to state specifics of your requirement ruling out a digital solution or even allowing a selection to be made between analog techniques.  **THIS IS A BAD QUESTION** showing that you learned nothing from your meta question about why the other bad question was closed.

Comment: The fact that you may not be interested in this in not a reason for other people not to be interested in it.

Comment: At least, if you are not interested in this topic, just admit that it can be of use for learning purposes.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum, it is a site reserved only for *specific questions* which can have specific answers.  **You do not have an answerably specific question**, if you want to have an open ended discussion about various techniques, you need to take it to a discussion forum, which is not what an SE site is.

Comment: Designing an square amplifier for use in analog computing (which can be used for educational purposes) is a perfectly specific question.

Comment: It's an overly *broad* question without a specific answer. Nevermind that you haven't actually asked a question anywhere in your 'question'.

Comment: @brhans : What kind of precision would you want me to bring ? In what way analog computing is not specific enough ?

Comment: You could start by asking a question. Questions often start with words like 'how', where', why' - and end with a `?`. It would probably also help you to spend a little time reading some of the [asking help pages](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/asking).

Comment: Ok, I put the question more clearly in the title and reworded the text somehow.

Comment: This app note from Analog Devices may give you some ideas: [Analog Multipliers](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-079.pdf)

Comment: Oh yes... I didn't think about the possibility to use log and antilog amplifiers

Answer (score 3):

This circuit will do squaring. I leave calibration, and temperature compensation, to you.

What is the bandwidth? at 1mA input, the 2N3904 will have about 40pF Cbe (computed from Ftau). With 100 ohm resistors, thus 4nanosecond Tau on nodes, BW is about 40MHz.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5U0sf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is this some "shared" information or this this something you designed ?